# Customise Firefox extension using chrome/userChrome.css

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, userchrome.css

I have foxclocks installed "{d37dc5d0-431d-44e5-8c91-49419370caa1}.xpi"

I have enabled use of chrome/userChrome.css and have hidden menu items so I know it is working.

I like to hide the "closer" in fox clocks but how do I reference it in chrome/userChrome.css

I tried

```
#closer { display: none !important }
```

but didnt work?

See image below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Works by doing the same with userContent.css and turning on

```
toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets to true
```

in about:config.